# Factorial through recursion

Tags: c++

It's a program of finding factorial using recursion & I don't know why this program is giving wrong output.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<conio.h>
using namespace std;
class factorial
{
    public:
    int fact(int n)
    {
        if (n==0)
        {
        cout<<"1";
        }
        else
        return n * fact(n-1);       
    }
};
int main()
{
    factorial s;
    s.fact(5);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hint: what is your `fact` function returning?

Comment: Your development environment likely comes with a debugging tool, and if it does not, get one that does. You can use a debugger to control the execution of your program, running it instruction by instruction if you have to, and inspect the the variables affected as you step. When you see the program do something it shouldn't have, you have found a bug.

Comment: Even when your program compiles, check the output for warnings. Errors prevent compilation, but warnings let you know that even though the program is grammatically correct, the logic probably isn't. Warnings are the first line of defense against simple logic errors like typos, ignored parameters, and forgotten return statements.

Comment: And besides the return problem mentioned above, what are you printing? This problem could be easily solved with a little [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging).

Comment: Your recent edit is better, but a function must have a return statement (or throw an exception) on all paths that exit the function. Once the result is returned, print the result.

Comment: `-Wall -Werror` if you're using gcc. Your function doesn't return an `int` if `n==0`, and luckily the compiler can tell you this automatically. Base cases are necessary for recursion to work.

Comment: I'm tempted to roll this question all the way back to version 1, which had no `return` statements at all. Don't make substantial edits to your code that invalidate existing answers, people.

Comment: Sarah, I have rolled back your question to a prior edit because the edits you made invalidated the answers. Please refrain from changing a question to make changes suggested by the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about your base case, which is the case of `n == 0`, which should return a value of 1. In your main function, you never output the value that is returned from your function.

Instead of `s.fact(5);`

try `cout<< s.fact(5);`

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious problem that is your program is *ill-formed*: the `int fact(int n)` function doesn't return a value if `n == 0`. The correct, well-formed solution would be:

```
int fact(int n)
{
    if (n == 0) return 1;
    return n * fact(n - 1);     
}
```

Comment: If I write my code with 'return 1' if (n==0) then it gives blank output.

Comment: @SarahKhaleel Try to output the return value of your `fact` function in the `main` function using `cout`. (and also remove the `cout` stuff from `fact`)